# Python Pandas: how to add a totally new column to a data frame inside of a groupby/transform operation

Tags: python, group-by, transform, dataframe, pandas

I want to mark some quantiles in my data, and for each row of the DataFrame, I would like the entry in a new column called e.g. "xtile" to hold this value.

For example, suppose I create a data frame like this:

```
import pandas, numpy as np
dfrm = pandas.DataFrame({'A':np.random.rand(100), 
                         'B':(50+np.random.randn(100)), 
                         'C':np.random.randint(low=0, high=3, size=(100,))})
```

And let's say I write my own function to compute the quintile of each element in an array. I have my own function for this, but for example just refer to scipy.stats.mstats.mquantile.

```
import scipy.stats as st
def mark_quintiles(x, breakpoints):
    # Assume this is filled in, using st.mstats.mquantiles.
    # This returns an array the same shape as x, with an integer for which
    # breakpoint-bucket that entry of x falls into.
```

Now, the real question is how to use `transform` to add a new column to the data. Something like this:

```
def transformXtiles(dataFrame, inputColumnName, newColumnName, breaks):
    dataFrame[newColumnName] = mark_quintiles(dataFrame[inputColumnName].values, 
                                              breaks)
    return dataFrame
```

And then:

```
dfrm.groupby("C").transform(lambda x: transformXtiles(x, "A", "A_xtile", [0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8, 1.0]))
```

The problem is that the above code will not add the new column "A_xtile". It just returns my data frame unchanged. If I first add a column full of dummy values, like NaN, called "A_xtile", then it *does* successfully over-write this column to include the correct quintile markings.

But it is extremely inconvenient to have to first write in the column for anything like this that I may want to add on the fly.

Note that a simple `apply` will not work here, since it won't know how to make sense of the possibly differently-sized result arrays for each group.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

What problems are you running into with `apply`? It works for this toy example here and the group lengths are different:

```
In [82]: df
Out[82]: 
   X         Y
0  0 -0.631214
1  0  0.783142
2  0  0.526045
3  1 -1.750058
4  1  1.163868
5  1  1.625538
6  1  0.076105
7  2  0.183492
8  2  0.541400
9  2 -0.672809

In [83]: def func(x):
   ....:     x['NewCol'] = np.nan
   ....:     return x
   ....: 

In [84]: df.groupby('X').apply(func)
Out[84]: 
   X         Y  NewCol
0  0 -0.631214     NaN
1  0  0.783142     NaN
2  0  0.526045     NaN
3  1 -1.750058     NaN
4  1  1.163868     NaN
5  1  1.625538     NaN
6  1  0.076105     NaN
7  2  0.183492     NaN
8  2  0.541400     NaN
9  2 -0.672809     NaN
```

Comment: It should be smart enough to know where to stick the group-specific pieces of that new column automatically. Basically, the syntax `df["NewCol"] = df.groupby("X").apply(some_inline_func)` should be analogous to the same thing as defining `some_inline_func` the way that you defined `func` above.

Comment: How about: `dfrm['A_xtile'] = dfrm.groupby('C').A.transform(mark_quintiles, [0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8, 1.0])`? (It seems to work on the latest pandas version haven't tried older ones)

Comment: This is excellent and deserves to be in the [pandas Split-Apply-Combine doc](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/groupby.html) I just spent 4 days trying out set_index, sort_index etc. to reinsert a groupby result back into its source dataframe.

Comment: @ChangShe when I try `df.groupby('X').apply(func)` the resulting dataframe is now indexed by the groupings it performed. How come yours does not behave this way?

Comment: @guy Add `group_keys=False` as an argument in `groupby`