# create new column using a shift within a groupby values

Tags: pandas

I want to create a new column which is a result of a shift function applied to a grouped values.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'X': [0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1], 'Y':[2,4,3,1,2,3,4,5]})

df

   X  Y
0  0  2
1  1  4
2  0  3
3  1  1
4  0  2
5  1  3
6  0  4
7  1  5

def func(x):                                                           
     x['Z'] = test['Y']-test['Y'].shift(1)
     return x

df_new = df.groupby('X').apply(func)

   X  Y    Z
0  0  2  NaN
1  1  4  2.0
2  0  3 -1.0
3  1  1 -2.0
4  0  2  1.0
5  1  3  1.0
6  0  4  1.0
7  1  5  1.0
```

As you can see from the output the values are shifted sequentally without accounting for a group by.

I have seen a similar question, but I could not figure out why it does not work as expected.

[Python Pandas: how to add a totally new column to a data frame inside of a groupby/transform operation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12389898/python-pandas-how-to-add-a-totally-new-column-to-a-data-frame-inside-of-a-group)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The values are shifted without accounting for the groups because your `func` uses `test` (presumably some other object, likely another name for what you call `df`) directly instead of simply the group `x`.

```
def func(x):                                                           
    x['Z'] = x['Y']-x['Y'].shift(1)
    return x
```

gives me

```
In [8]: df_new
Out[8]: 
   X  Y    Z
0  0  2  NaN
1  1  4  NaN
2  0  3  1.0
3  1  1 -3.0
4  0  2 -1.0
5  1  3  2.0
6  0  4  2.0
7  1  5  2.0
```

but note that in this particular case you don't need to write a custom function, you can just call `diff` on the groupby object directly.  (Of course other functions you might want to work with may be more complicated).

```
In [13]: df_new["Z2"] = df.groupby("X")["Y"].diff()

In [14]: df_new
Out[14]: 
   X  Y    Z   Z2
0  0  2  NaN  NaN
1  1  4  NaN  NaN
2  0  3  1.0  1.0
3  1  1 -3.0 -3.0
4  0  2 -1.0 -1.0
5  1  3  2.0  2.0
6  0  4  2.0  2.0
7  1  5  2.0  2.0
```